# "Users not adding their phone numbers and accepting the TOS will be rejected"

Tags: grammar

I'm using a contrived example here, but am curious about the meaning of the below quotation:

> "Users not adding their phone numbers and accepting the TOS will be rejected"

Is there ambiguity in that language as to which users would be rejected?

Possible scenarios:

1. User adding the phone number and accepting the TOS
2. User adding their phone number but not accepting the TOS
3. User not adding their phone number but accepting the TOS
4. User not adding their phone number and not accepting the TOS

I am most interested in #2 above.

Comment: To clarify, does this quotation mean: (a) NOT(adding phone number AND accepting the TOS) or (b) NOT(adding phone number) AND accepting the TOS

Comment: It sounds like there may be many reasons for a user to be rejected. For example, not accepting the TOS might be grounds for rejection, regardless of whether you provide a phone number or not. While it's not possible to infer this from the original quote, I think the language of it is pretty clear: no number + TOS = rejection.

Comment: How could scenario 1 possibly be the meaning? The quote clearly says "not", yet that scenario doesn't have either action negated.

Answer (score 0):

While it's grammatically ambiguous, I think most would understand it to mean that both the phone number and TOS acceptance are required. If rejection were contingent on just one requirement, there would be no need to mention the other; it's common to assume that if you mention something it's salient, and then use this understanding to disambiguate the language.

You can usually avoid this problem by stating requirements in a positive sense. Or split the sentence into multiple sentences.

Note that the way this is parsed and understood may differ depending on the specific actions. Consider

> Users not adding their phone numbers and submitting the form will be rejected.

In this case, *submitting the form* is presumably not a condiction for or against rejection, but a prerequisite for being considered. You can't be accepted or rejected if you never submit the form in the first place. So the only rejection condition would be not adding the phone numbers. But I think this would be more commonly written as:

> Users submitting the form without adding their phone numbers will be rejected.

Comment: Your final suggestion is grammatically correct but sounds awkward to me. I recommend *Users submitting the form without adding their phone numbers will be rejected.*. Or better, *Users who submit the form without adding their phone numbers will be rejected.*

Comment: @sgroves How about my update, with parenthetical commas?

Comment: The commas are unnecessary. I think the "but" is the problem in the sentence. I'm no linguist so this is hard to describe, but your version sounds like *submitting the form* and *adding their phone numbers* are separate and unrelated actions, when they are actually quite related. This might just be a matter of opinion, though.

Comment: I see your point. I think it will usually be clear from context -- if the form is known to have a phone number field on it, it's obvious that this is referring to whether that field is filled in.

Comment: @sgroves But I don't think the *but/without* distinction is very significant. Consider "Users submitting the form without pushing the red button" versus "Users submitting the form but not pushing the red button". In both cases, pushing the red button is a separate action, and the meanings are the same.

Comment: I disagree. Like I said, the "but" version sounds weird to me. It could just be a matter of opinion, but I would personally never say it like that. Just sounds weird. Even better than those two would be *Users submitting the form without having pushed the red button* IMO.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of personal preference, but I agree that I'd be more likely to say *without*, so I've changed the answer. As to your last version, it depends on whether you have to push the button before, after, or concurrently with submitting.

Comment: @sgroves Another variation: *Users who have submitted the form but have not <whatever> will be rejected*

Comment: I think that's the whole problem. The "but" version, to me, makes it seem like you need to push the button concurrently with submitting, which makes no sense. The "without" version makes it clear (to me) that you're supposed to push the button *before* submitting the form.